# Error While Push Notification in Android using aws amplify notification (React Native)

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have been following https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/testing-push-notifications-with-aws-amplify-9126bd621d3a... during
`aws2 pinpoint send-messages --cli-input-json file://pinpoint-send-messages.json`

gives an error

````
  "MessageResponse": {
    "ApplicationId": "YOUR AWS PINPOINT PROJECT ID",
    "EndpointResult": {
      "YOUR ENDPOINT ID": {
        "DeliveryStatus": "PERMANENT_FAILURE",
                "StatusCode": 410,
                "StatusMessage": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Unregistered or expired token\",\"channelType\":\"GCM\",\"pushProviderStatusCode\":\"200\",\"pushProviderError\":\"InvalidRegistration\",\"pushProviderResponse\":\"{\\\"results\\\":[{\\\"error\\\":\\\"InvalidRegistration\\\"}],\\\"multicast_id\\\":\\\"1231312312312312\\\",\\\"success\\\":0,\\\"failure\\\":1,\\\"canonical_ids\\\":0}\"}" 
            }
      }
    },
  }
}```
````

Comment: have you figured this out? Mine works if I use device token to push notification but I am getting this error when I use endpoint id.

Comment: ya. didn't work with endpoint id.. But you can create topics and send the notification to a required topic subscriber.

Comment: I see. I haven't looked into topics so no idea right now. I will look into that. Thanks for the suggestion.